# Plot pandas dataframe with subplots (subplots=True): Place legend and use tight layout

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I really like pandas to handle and analyze big datasets. So far, I have mostly used matplotlib for plotting but now want to use pandas own plot  functionalities (based on matplotlib) since it needs less code and seems to be sufficient for me in most cases. Especially the subplots to have a guick glance at big dataframes like in the following example..

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate random data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(96,12),
                  columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J',
                           'K', 'L'])

# Plotting
df.plot(kind='line', subplots=True, grid=True, title="Sample Data (Unit)",
        layout=(4, 3), sharex=True, sharey=False, legend=True,    
        style=['r', 'r', 'r', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'r', 'r', 'r'],
        xticks=np.arange(0, len(df), 16))
```

[image]

..which brings me to my questions:

1.) How can I place all legends in the subplots at the same place (e. g. centered, outside, topright)?

2.) Can I somehow use matplotlibs "Tight Layout" (http://matplotlib.org/users/tight_layout_guide.html) for the plot?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

1. You can have all the legends in the same place, but you would have to create them in a separate step.

   ```
   # Plotting
   df.plot(kind='line', subplots=True, grid=True, title="Sample Data (Unit)",
       layout=(4, 3), sharex=True, sharey=False, legend=False,    
       style=['r', 'r', 'r', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'r', 'r', 'r'],
       xticks=np.arange(0, len(df), 16))

   for ax in plt.gcf().axes:
       ax.legend(loc=1)
   ```
2. Sure. just use `plt.tight_layout()` before you `show` or `savefig`. Compare the two examples below created with and without `tight_layout`.

Without `tight_layout()`:

[image]

With `tight_layout()`:

[image]

Comment: @tom I was looking for help with the tight_layout() function, which was not working for me when using pandas and the subplot feature. However, I found a way using subplots_adjust(). Thanks for your attention