# How to change the legend location for pandas subplots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, legend

I'm trying to create a pandas plot with a large number of subplots, 58 in this case. The data is wide form in a format similar to this:

```
df = 

Date It1 It2 It3... Itn 
0    x    x   x      n
1    x    x   x      n
2    x    x   x      n
3    x    x   x      n
```

I have been able to create the plot no problem with pandas plot:

```
rows = df.shape[1]//2
df.plot(legend = True, subplots = True, layout = (rows,5), grid=True, title="Labs", sharex=True, sharey=False,figsize=(12,32),)
plt.show()
```

But am having trouble setting the position of the legend so all of the graphs are legible, this is an example of how the currently look:

[image]

I've tried both solutions in this other stack overflow post - [Set the legend location of a pandas plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59791884/set-the-legend-location-of-a-pandas-plot)

... but neither actually work. I also tried using tight_layout() per this answer but it is equally illegible - [Plot pandas dataframe with subplots (subplots=True): Place legend and use tight layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33959124/plot-pandas-dataframe-with-subplots-subplots-true-place-legend-and-use-tight)

Can anyone offer any guidance as to how to place the legends of a chart with so many graphs on it and still keep it readable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) with `subplots=True` returns a `numpy.ndarray` of [`matplotlib.axes.Axes`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes)
- The easiest way to access each subplot `axes` is to flatten the array, and iterate through each.
- Use the answers to [How to put the legend out of the plot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4700614/7758804) to place the legend in an appropriate location.
- Other `axes` level modifications can be made inside the loop using the standard matplotlib object orient methods (i.e. those beginning with `ax.`).
- `figsize` must be adjusted depending the number of rows and cols.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# # sinusoidal sample data
sample_length = range(1, 15+1)
rads = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 0.01)
data = np.array([np.sin(t*rads) for t in sample_length])
df = pd.DataFrame(data.T, index=pd.Series(rads.tolist(), name='radians'), columns=[f'freq: {i}x' for i in sample_length])

# plot the data with subplots and assign the returned array
axes = df.plot(subplots=True, layout=(3, 5), figsize=(25, 15))

# flatten the array
axes = axes.flat  # .ravel() and .flatten() also work

# extract the figure object to use figure level methods
fig = axes[0].get_figure()

# iterate through each axes to use axes level methods
for ax in axes:
    
    ax.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 1.10), frameon=False)
    
fig.suptitle('Sinusoids of Different Frequency', fontsize=22, y=0.95)
plt.show()
```

[image]